# php issue with dates

Tags: php, date

I'm writing this code:

```
$dateQueried = '2013-03-18';
$reservQuery = "SELECT * FROM bkng WHERE ArrivalDate <= '$dateQueried' AND DepartureDate > '$dateQueried'";
$rsrv = mysql_query($reservQuery) or die(mysql_error());
$resRow = mysql_fetch_row($rsrv);
$DateIn = strtotime($resRow["ArrivalDate"]);
$DateOut = strtotime($resRow["DepartureDate"]);
$dateQueried = strtotime($dateQueried);
if ($DateIn = $dateQueried) {
echo 'case 1';
} elseif ($DateIn < $dateQueried) {
echo 'case 2';
} else {
echo 'case 3';
}
```

Problem is that i can't get into case 2 or case 3...is there something I have missed?

I tried printing the variables and tried also putting them into `var_dump()`: outside the if it returns for example "String(10) '2013-03-18'" while insted into the if it returns "NULL"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator. By using `=` you're assigning the value to `$dateIn` which is always true and will always cause that code block to execute.

```
if ($DateIn = $dateQueried) {
```

should be

```
if ($DateIn == $dateQueried) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($DateIn = $dateQueried) {
```

is wrong, its an assignment. It should be

```
if ($DateIn == $dateQueried) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is not a comparison operator, it's the assignment operator. The assignment always succeeds, hence it always goes outputs `case 1`, because it *is* indeed always true.

You should simply change your `=` for `==` for the comparison.

```
if ($DateIn == $dateQueried) {
```

Answer (score -3):

1. `var_dump($dateQueried, $DateIn, $resRow["ArrivalDate"]);`
2. Think.
3. That == thing everyone mentioned
4. Learn to *debug* your code

Comment: @l736k his answers is all like that. Do not get distracted by him and look for other answers. Good luck!